# How to concat with linq?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have this tables at sql server:

```
id_service      name
1               ejemplo 1
2               ejemplo 2     


id_service      id_quality
1               1
1               2

id_quality      quality
1               simple
2               full
```

and Im trying to get this:

```
id_service      qualities
1               Simple \n Full
```

I´m working with linq, is there any way to do it???

I have this so far, but it returns two rows instead of one as I need

```
var services = from service in dc.service

                        join s_quality in dc.service_quality
                        on service.id_service equals s_quality.id_service

                        join qualityObj in dc.quality
                        on s_quality.id_quality equals qualityObj.id_quality

                        select new {service.id_service, qualityObj.quality1};
        GridView1.DataSource = services;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

The ending grid should look like this:

```
    id_service          name              quality available
    1                   Company 1         1 - simple
                                          2 - full
    --------------------------------------------------------
    2                   Company 2         1 - simple  

                                          (this column should have grouped or concat results)
```

Comment: It would help if you had English names of the variables and columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
var servicios = from servicio in dc.servicio
                join s_calidad in dc.servicio_calidad
                on servicio.id_servicio equals s_calidad.id_servicio

                join calidadObj in dc.calidad
                on s_calidad.id_calidad equals calidadObj.id_calidad

                group new {servicio.id_servicio, calidadObj.calidad1} by servicio.id_servicio into grouping
                select new { groupning.Key, Concat = string.Join(",", grouping.Select(g => g.calidad1)) };
```

You can write your own concatenation logic for Concat property in the anonimous type

Comment: I have tried it, but it did not resulted. I made an edition to my answer, maybe its more clear. I need in one row, where some columns have one field, one last column with one o more fields grouped or concatenated